# onClick not wokring in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**'onClick' is not working right now.Can somebody help me with this?**
I've removed all the unneccesary things. I should be getting message 'inside this was clicked' but I am not getting it.

```
import * as bootstrap from 'react-bootstrap';
import * as utilsHelper from '../../helpers/utils';

import {genEntityIconHTMLElement, getEntityLabel} from '../../helpers/entity';

import {FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import {isNil, isNil as _isNil} from 'lodash';
import request from "superagent-bluebird-promise";
import SearchField from "./parts/search-field";
import SearchResults from "./parts/search-results";


const {Alert, Button, Col, Grid, ListGroup, ListGroupItem, Row, ButtonGroup, DropdownButton, MenuItem, Pager} = bootstrap;
const {formatDate} = utilsHelper;

class RevisionsPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.thisWasClicked = this.thisWasClicked.bind(this);
    }

    thisWasClicked(event) {
        alert("inside this was Clicked");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="revisionPage">
                <h1 onClick={this.thisWasClicked}>working?</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default RevisionsPage;
```

Comment: there is no problem in your onClick function code...problem is something elase. check again

Comment: Maybe check if you have disabled browser alerts or something else, because this code works fine on my machine.

Comment: Thanks. I will check

Comment: You can try this as well <h1 onClick={this.thisWasClicked.bind(this)}>working?</h1>

Answer (score 1):

You should try arrow function rather than bind method, ES6 provides the best way to event bind using an arrow function.

Please try below code using the arrow function

```
import * as bootstrap from 'react-bootstrap';
import * as utilsHelper from '../../helpers/utils';

import {genEntityIconHTMLElement, getEntityLabel} from '../../helpers/entity';

import {FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import {isNil, isNil as _isNil} from 'lodash';
import request from "superagent-bluebird-promise";
import SearchField from "./parts/search-field";
import SearchResults from "./parts/search-results";


const {Alert, Button, Col, Grid, ListGroup, ListGroupItem, Row, ButtonGroup, DropdownButton, MenuItem, Pager} = bootstrap;
const {formatDate} = utilsHelper;

class RevisionsPage extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    thisWasClicked = (event) => {
        alert("inside this was Clicked");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="revisionPage">
                <h1 onClick={this.thisWasClicked}>working?</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default RevisionsPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe arrow function will help you:

```
import * as bootstrap from 'react-bootstrap';
import * as utilsHelper from '../../helpers/utils';

import {genEntityIconHTMLElement, getEntityLabel} from '../../helpers/entity';

import {FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import {isNil, isNil as _isNil} from 'lodash';
import request from "superagent-bluebird-promise";
import SearchField from "./parts/search-field";
import SearchResults from "./parts/search-results";


const {Alert, Button, Col, Grid, ListGroup, ListGroupItem, Row, ButtonGroup, DropdownButton, MenuItem, Pager} = bootstrap;
const {formatDate} = utilsHelper;

class RevisionsPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    thisWasClicked = () => {
        alert("inside this was Clicked");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="revisionPage">
                <h1 onClick={() => this.thisWasClicked()}>working?</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default RevisionsPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code is working I've create [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uL3yoc5j/6/)

But the `.bind()` method is the old way to bind `this` to an event. Now you would use an arrow function

```
class RevisionsPage extends React.Component {

    thisWasClicked = (event) => {
        alert("inside this was Clicked");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="revisionPage">
                <h1 onClick={this.thisWasClicked}>working?</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

It makes your constructor become useless. So you get a shorter code.

I hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks. I guess problem is with some other things. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of both bind and arrow function

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.thisWasClicked = this.thisWasClicked.bind(this);
  }
  thisWasClicked(event) {
    alert("inside this was Clicked");
  }
  handleClick = e => {
    alert("Arrow Clicked");
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1 onClick={this.thisWasClicked}>working?</h1>
        <h2 onClick={this.handleClick}>Arrow</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that you did not block the alerts for the webpage that you are working on? Close the browser tab and open again to test it. Or just write `console.log("Test");` to test if your button functions properly.

Answer (score 0):

it's working for me. i copied same code from your question,[alert working demo in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-rgb-765tj)
perhaps something to do with other removed code?